# The sum of 2 consecutive numbers is 53.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of 2 consecutive numbers is 53.

I need to find those numbers, but I'm not even sure how to set up the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you start with $n,n+1?$

Comment: Play around a little bit, "trial and error." You will soon find the answer, and the playing will give you information about what happens in general.

Comment: The usual approach is to give things names. Let $a$ be the first number and $b$ be the second number. The next step is to turn words into equations. Write down equations that mean the same thing as "$a,b$ are consecutive numbers" and "their sum is $53$".

Comment: If you have problems setting up the problem, then you should say so. If you don't, then as you've noticed, you will get some answers that *don't even try* to explain this to you, and they just assume you understand that part and are having trouble with equation solving. (also, it would look less like you're trying to get people to do your homework for you)

Answer (score 3):

Two *consecutive* numbers are pairs of numbers like $\,1, 2\,$ or $\,18, 19$: "one right after the other". That is, one of the integers is immediately to the right of the other, when viewed on a number line.

Denote the smaller integer using $n$. Then the larger of the two *consecutive* integers must be $n+1$.  That leaves us with solving the following: $$n + (n+1) =  2n + 1 =53.$$

That means $\;2n = 53-1 = 52,\;$ so $\;n =\dfrac {52}2 = 26$.

So, we have $\;n = 26, \;n+1 = 27,$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$$x+(x+1)=53 \iff 2x+1=53 \iff 2x=52 \iff x=26$$

The numbers are:

$x=26$ and $x+1=27$